# Использование groupby вместо apply

Tags: python, dataframe

Как заменить apply на groupby для подсчета кол-во совпадающих элементов исходного множества во множеством значений заданых в строках в массиве dataframe, чтобы новый код был более производительный чем исходный?
Планирую использовать код на кол-во записей порядка 40 000 000.

Исходный рабочий код

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7]])
print(df)
s = {1,3}


hints = df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & s), axis=1).value_counts().sort_index()
print(hints)
```

Исходные данные:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5  6
3  4  5  6  7
```

Результат:

```
0    1
1    2
2    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю как здесь можно применить `groupby`, но вы можете заменить `apply()` на комбинацию `isin()` и `sum()`:

```
hints = df.isin(s).sum(1).value_counts().sort_index()
```

Чуть подробнее:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7]] * 1_000_000)

In [3]: len(df.index)
Out[3]: 4000000

In [4]: s = {1,3}

In [5]: df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & s), axis=1).value_counts().sort_index()
Out[5]: 
0    1000000
1    2000000
2    1000000
dtype: int64

In [6]: df.isin(s).sum(1).value_counts().sort_index()
Out[6]: 
0    1000000
1    2000000
2    1000000
dtype: int64

In [7]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & s), axis=1).value_counts().sort_index()
2min 34s ± 4.76 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [8]: %timeit df.isin(s).sum(1).value_counts().sort_index()
840 ms ± 7.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```